# change initial interface controller in watchKit

Tags: ios, swift, watchkit, apple-watch

I have two interface controllers, `controller1.swift` and `controller2.swift`

These are connected with *push-segue* (after button action). But in some cases I need to skip `controller1` and show just `controller2`. In iOS app I do this in `appDelegate`, setting `rootViewcontroller`, etc. What is the way to do this in Apple Watch Extension?

any guides or help?

Comment: maybe this will help you http://makeapppie.com/2015/06/10/swift-watchkit-working-with-modal-views-part-2-presenting-programmatically/

Answer (score 8):

```
let rootControllerIdentifier = "FirstInputInterfaceController"

WKInterfaceController.reloadRootControllers(withNames: [rootControllerIdentifier], contexts: nil)
```

---

#### Swift 4:

```
let rootControllerIdentifier = "FirstInputInterfaceController"
WKInterfaceController.reloadRootControllers(withNamesAndContexts: [(name: rootControllerIdentifier, context: [:] as AnyObject)])
```

Answer (score 1):

After long research work I found only one solution - create some SplashController, with some splash screen, and in

```
override func awakeWithContext(context: AnyObject?) {
    super.awakeWithContext(context)
}
```

track something that you need, after track present some controllers, example

```
    if !isCounting {
        self.presentControllerWithName("Interface", context: nil)
    } else {
        self.presentControllerWithName("Timer", context: nil)
    }
```

hope it will help someone.
P.S. isCounting is stored in NSUserDefaults